# Value of optional type 'Question?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'questionText' of wrapped base type 'Question'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am making a small question and answer ios app.  I want the first question to be randomized.  The code I have is below.

```
let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
var pickedAnswer : Bool = false
//Place your instance variables here


@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var progressBar: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list.randomElement();
    questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText

}
```

I am accessing the array with .list but I want the first question to be a random element each time the app is launched.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `firstQuestion` can be `nil`, so it's of type `Question?`. If you want to use its `questionText` property, you have to unwrap your question. One way is by optional-binding

```
if let firstQuestion = allQuestions.list.randomElement() {
    questionLabel.text = firstQuestion.questionText
}
```

Comment: Cheers for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

If `list` were empty, there would be no element to select and `randomElement` would return `nil`. This is similar to `.first` or `.last` properties.

You can handle that simply using optional chaining:

```
let firstQuestion: Question? = allQuestions.list.randomElement()
questionLabel.text = firstQuestion?.questionText
```

Since `list` is probably never empty, this situation will actually never happen. We just have to handle that because the compiler cannot be sure.

Comment: Now I feel like... I forgot for optional chaining :(

Comment: @RobertDresler This works only because `UILabel.text` can take an optional. It's just one of the options.